# Is there anything wrong with my sitemap index?

Tags: seo, xml-sitemap

I have one sitemap index:

```
https://example.com/sitemap-index.xml.gz
```

There is only one sitemap in it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sitemapindex xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    <sitemap>
        <loc>https://example.com/sitemap-0.xml</loc>
    </sitemap>
</sitemapindex>
```

There are ~12k URLs in `https://example.com/sitemap-0.xml`

When I uploaded it to Bing Webmaster Tools, I got:
[image]

However, when I uploaded the same sitemap index to Google Search Console, there is no problem:
[image]

Is there anything wrong with Bing?

Edit:

As mentioned by @StephenOstermiller, I tried to submit `https://example.com/sitemap-0.xml` directly to Bing. Following is what I got:
[image]
Shouldn't it display 12.6K? I'm still debugging what's wrong with the index file though.

Comment: With 12k URLs it looks like you don't need an index.  Have you tried submitting `https://example.com/sitemap-0.xml` directly rather than submitting an index with just that one sub-sitemap?

Comment: I also had a lot of difficulties submitting my sitemap to bing. And I find it hard to troubleshoot there, since the error messages are not very helpful.  My guess is that the bing webmaster guidelines must be followed relatively strictly so that your URLs get indexed by bing